# When does a web server clear the PHP session identifier?

Tags: php, http, session, curl

**Background:**

I am trying to write a script that connects on a regular basis to a web server and checks if some information on a specific page was changed. I already got this working using a combination of bash (for scripting), curl (for the actual connection) and crontab (for the scheduling).

Since the server requires authentication, I first used curl to do a POST request on the login page with my credentials and saved the cookie file (containing the PHPSESSID). Now i can use the cookie file when doing the request for the actual web page I want to check.

**Question(s):**

1. When does the server actually clear the PHPSESSID i set with my first request? I imagine it must do this sometime, otherwise it would crash because it keeps storing information about every single session that was ever started.
2. If the PHPSESSID is cleared on closing the browser is there some way i can simulate that even using curl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little more complicated than just "when it's cleared"

A session has a lifetime in PHP. The default is 24 minutes. That means that after you connect to a website, your session is valid until

- You close the browser (which won't be simulated with cURL unless you just drop the cookies)

  OR
- 24 minutes pass

Each time you load a page and the server calls `session_start()` that expiration time will be bumped an additional 24 minutes (technically speaking it's actually bumped 24 minutes at the end of the script execution on pages where `session_start()` is called).

When that cookie actually expires, your session is no longer valid, and `$_SESSION` will be empty on the server side. **But your data is still on the server** until the next time that the server performs a session garbage collection cycle to clear out expired sessions which, depending on the session handler in use on the server, may or may not actually delete your data. A bank, for example, might send the data off to an archive server in case they ever need the records.

Comment: @Blacksonic Yeah, pretty common. I tend to post quickly and then realize things I want to change after I actually read them back to myself again.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. One thing, though: I managed to access the page today using a cookie file I saved yesterday. So, what would be the best approach: keep re-using the sessionID I got the first time (and only request another if that fails) or request a new one each time?

Comment: @MasterF 24 minutes is the default session lifetime. It's up to the server administrator if they want to change that. Many websites actually make the session expiration something like 30 days (virtually unlimited for daily-use websites). I would only request a new one if you fail to load the page with your current one.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer that approach since it only involves a single request most of time.

Answer (score 4):

The server removes the session after the session timeout-time has passed after the last request. This is by default 1440 seconds (24 minutes), it can be changed in php.ini file.

The session is not flushed serverside on closing the browser, the client loses his session data though, since the browser deletes his local memory of the session. But if you keep your sessionid somewhere safe you can use it later on again, if you stay within the timeout frame of course.

This is exactly how session hijackings work, they get your sessionid in some way and can then set this sessionid on their own machine and continue your session.